# python dictionary parameter to JS dictionary with flask templates

Tags: python, flask

I have a dictionary in flask server with python3.6 and want to move the dict_test dictionary as Javascript dictionary using flask template framework. Which is the way?

flask-server.py

```
@app.route("/app", methods=['GET'])
def home():
    dict_test = {"key1":10, "k2":'hello'}
    return render_template("index.html", text_lists=dict_test)


logging.info("Listener started")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

index.html

```
    <body>
      <script>
          var tp_data = {{text_lists}};
      </script>
             ....
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your dictionary into json using `simplejson`:

```py
return render_template("index.html", text_lists=simplejson.dumps(dict_test))
```

In your index.html you can access `text_lists` like you did.

```html
var tp_data = {{text_lists | safe}};
```

When you add `|safe` you're telling that you have already escaped the text and it is safe to render this directly.

Comment: I wanted a dictionary in Javascript, and simplejson.dumps() returns a string, right?

Comment: The `.py` side converts it to a valid JSON object. I am using `dumps` with some parameters like `ignore_nan=True` to ensure that the js-object will be valid to what I need.

Answer (score 1):

This way worked for me:

flask-server.py

```
return render_template("index.html", text_lists=dict_test)
```

index.html

```
var tp_data = {{text_lists | tojson }};
```